# Angular 5 and PHP cannot decrypt an encrypted variable in php using cryptoJS

Tags: php, angular, encryption, angular5, cryptojs

I am using the crypto-js library to send some encrypted variables from angular 5 to PHP. Everything is working fine until I added the crypto-aes.php library to my php script.

```
ngOnInit(){
let user = "am";
let key = "pizza";
let enc = crypto.AES.encrypt(user, key);
//console.log(enc);
let dec = crypto.AES.decrypt(enc, key);
//console.log(dec.toString(crypto.enc.Utf8));

const headerOptions = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
headerOptions.set('Content-Type', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin')
const params = new HttpParams().set('name', enc)
this.http.post('http://aff.local/test.php', params, {
    headers: headerOptions
}).subscribe(
        res=>{
            console.log(res);
            alert(res)
        },
        error=>{
            console.log(error);
        }
    )
}
```

And here is my PHP script:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include('./cryptojs-aes.php');
ini_set('log_errors', 0);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$host = "localhost";
$db = "dentist";
$user = "root";
$pass = "root";

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$db};", $user, $pass);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4");
$enc = $_POST['name'];
$key = "pizza";
$dec = cryptoJSAesDecrypt($key, $enc);
echo $dec;
```

The problem is that the alerted and consoled result is `null`

Comment: Why are you doing this instead of using HTTPS?

Comment: Just for testing the crypto library and see if I can use it in later projects.

Comment: You understand that symmetric encryption doesn't really work here right?  The encryption key can be determined by any user...

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark how it would be determined if I am not sending it anywhere.

Comment: Angular is client side...  Anyone can view your source code and derive the key in the same way you do.  With respect, there isn't really any excuse these days to not use HTTPS to solve this problem.

Comment: Not to mention you ARE sending it somewhere because you send the logic from your webserver to the client when you serve the script file...